# How to know which package makes 'tntnet' service autostart?

Tags: 12.04

tntnet uses port 80, which makes apache not started.
How to know which package makes 'tntnet' service autostart?
Can I cancel it from autostart ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> General answer

If the software is made for Linux there should only be one location:

```
/etc/init.d/
```

There should be a script there called `tntnet` and this should be either an upstart script (new method) or an init script (old method).

Just to prove it I installed it ;)

> Specific for tntnet

```
pwd
/etc/init.d
ls tnt*
tntnet
```

and the file itself:

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          tntnet.org
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $time $network
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $time $network
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: modular, multithreaded web application server for C++
# Description:       web server in which dynamic content can be written in
#                    ecpp, where C++ code can be embedded in HTML layout.
### END INIT INFO

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DAEMON=/usr/bin/tntnet
NAME=tntnet
DESC=tntnet

test -x $DAEMON || exit 0
```

To stop `tntnet` from auto starting you can do `tntnet stop` from command line or remove the service. This should work:

```
update-rc.d tntnet disable
```

Comment: Thanks! Is tntnet critical to normal system ?

Comment: no,you need to install it yourself no it is non-critical.